# iOS hold gesture

Tags: ios

I've been trying a lot to make something and I couldn't, please help me. I have a variable that is 3 for example and I want it to increase when the user touches the screen and holds it so. For example if he taps the screen only, the variable will be 3, if he holds for 2 seconds the variable will be 5, if he holds for 5 seconds, the variable will be 10. Something like that, the more the user holds the more the variable will increase. Please help me!

Comment: Have you looked at UIGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Yes, specifically look into UITapGestureRecognizer and UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Yes, I have looked and I couldn't do it.

Comment: What problem did you have with it? Did you get an error? Did you see an incorrect response? We need more details to help you.

Comment: I wonder unless I can find a method like the one implemented in Unity. When I worked in Unity, the function for hold is called multiple times while the user keeps the touch hold. In xcode, when the user holds the touch, the function is called one time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you are describing simply by adding multiple gesture recognizers to the same view. What you are probably looking for is the [gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) method in the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.

This method allows multiple gestures to be recognized simultaneously, which is not the default behavior for gesture recognizers.

The following code does exactly what you are describing.

```
@interface ViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger variable;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.variable = 0;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                          action:@selector(firstMethod)];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *press = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(secondMethod)];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *secondPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(thirdMethod)];

    press.minimumPressDuration = 2;
    secondPress.minimumPressDuration = 5;

    press.delegate = self;
    secondPress.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:press];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:secondPress];
}

- (void)firstMethod
{
    self.variable = 2;
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.variable);
}

- (void)secondMethod
{
    self.variable = 5;
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.variable);
}

- (void)thirdMethod
{
    self.variable = 10;
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.variable);
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```